# Does the Samsung Galaxy 5 support Band 12 LTE?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, 4g

Does the Samsung Galaxy 5 support Band 12 with AOSP/CM13?

Answer (score 0):

## No, it doesn't have the hardware

Here is the [T-Mobile spec sheet for the Galaxy S5](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-10409) that seems to indicate it doesn't support Band 12.

```
Network
2G/3G/4G/LTE Capable
UMTS: Band V (850); UMTS/HSPA+: AWS Band IV / 2100 / 1900 / 850;Band II (1900);Quad Band GSM;LTE
  GSM/GPRS/EDGE: 850/900/1800/1900MHz
```

And, here is the [Spec Sheet from Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SM-G900TZKATMB) that seems to indicate it doesn't support Band 12,

```
Network
FREQUENCIES AND DATA TYPE
LTE: Bands 1/2/3/5/7/8/4/17 HSPA+/UMTS: 850/AWS/1900/2100MHz GSM: 850/900/1800/1900MHz
```